# Firefox similar tool to Chome JavaScript Tracker

Tags: javascript, web-development, html, firefox

I'm looking for a Firefox tool that has the same features as Google Chrome extension: [JavaScript Tracker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-tracker/pdkjocgjcabjddpnefbdkdeadfancbgh), i.e. can investigate which JS code causes a DOM modification on the specified element.